# SQL Query unable to create database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users'(
'id' INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'username' VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
'password' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
'email' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 'created_at' DATETIME NOT NULL,
 'updated_at' DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY('id'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'email'('email')
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

> Error : A symbol name was expected! (near "'id'" at position 39)
>   At least one column definition was expected. (near "'id'" at position 39)
>   Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10" at position 48)
>   Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT NULL" at position 52)

Comment: which database you are using  ????

Comment: why do you use apostrophes for your table and column names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: in phpmyadmin i am creating it

Comment: tag question in [tag:mysql].

Comment: remove the single quote with backtics.

Comment: You should use backtics and not single quote around the column name

Comment: Thanks Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `backticks` instead of `single quotes`.

` instead of- '